# Rails API, how to set/override handlers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am trying to extend a Rails MVC controller at a different namespace and have the subclass act as a REST api to accept and return JSON instead of dealing with views.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :companies

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json} do
      resources :companies
    end
  end
```

However, when I call the /api/v1/companies route, I get an error "Missing Template" complaining that there is no view. In the detail, I see some handlers that make me think it's trying to process a .erb file.

```
    Missing template api/v1/companies/show, companies/show, application/show with
 {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.
```

Here is my api/v1/companies_controller

```
class Api::V1::CompaniesController < CompaniesController

  def show
    super
  end

end
```

Is there any way I can make it so that rails doesn't try to find a view template and just returns the json?

Comment: can u post your `companies_controller.rb` file, that located in api folder.

Comment: @7urkm3n Added above. That's it for now, just trying to do a basic GET on /api/vi/companies/1

Comment: did u try to add on controller `respond_to :json`, add it right below `CompaniesController`,  also `respond_with(@object)` in the show method.

Comment: Just tried it - didn't clear it up.

Comment: Actually, that did work. Can you add as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should render always as `JSON`

```
class Api::V1::CompaniesController < CompaniesController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with(@object) # pass your own object 
  end

end
```